# Showing only one parameter of custom object in dropdown menu using AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, autocompletetextview

I want to show only one parameter from object(s) found using `AutoCompleteTextView`. I have list of custom items and I'm using this list in `ArrayAdapter` which is used in my `AutoCompleteTextView`. But as I find item by typing something to `AutoCompleteTextView`, only object as whole is shown (Object type and some identifier), but I want to show just Objects attribute `"name"` which is a `String`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way i'd go about this is making a separate arraylist with all the names inside of it. Display that and get the user to chose from there, once they have use the index to find the object in the other list.

Comment: This is working fine (I hope that this Adapter is not working as Adapter in RecyclerView which position will change overtime. (Getting item in setonClickItemListener by position)

Answer (score 0):

Initiate new string array

```js
String[] data = new String[1]);  // terms is a List<String>
```

```js
for(int i=0;i<=1;i++){ //only the 1st position of ur data getting inserted
data[0]=s.get(i).toString();
}

ArrayAdapter<?> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Object>(activity, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, data);
keywordField.setAdapter(adapter);  // keywordField is a AutoCompleteTextView
```